# Timedelta to total_seconds() outputs the "wrong" total seconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

i am stuck with a small problem and i dont understand the problem.

I calculated the time difference between two datetime columns. As an output i receive this:
[image]

when i want to convert that to total_seconds i receive this output:

[image]

which is basically correct when i divide it by the factor 1000. Can someone explain me why i dont get the correct output with the function "total_seconds()"?

I do it with the following code:

```py
for rows in df_ausfallmeldung.index:
    if df_ausfallmeldung["Prognose"][rows] is pd.NaT:
        ergebnis = (df_ausfallmeldung["Soll"][rows] - df_ausfallmeldung["Eingang"][rows]).total_seconds()

        df_ausfallmeldung.loc[rows, "Abweichung"] = ergebnis

    else:
        ergebnis = (df_ausfallmeldung["Prognose"][rows] - df_ausfallmeldung["Eingang"][rows]).total_seconds()

        df_ausfallmeldung.loc[rows, "Abweichung"] = ergebnis
```

It is not working i alway get the same output. All data in the columns is dtype (datetime). The value "ergebnis" is timedelta.

Update: The calculation was always right. The problem is the output to the csv file.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. Show code that **someone else can copy and paste, without changing or adding anything**, to reproduce the problem directly. (This means: make sure the program can create the necessary data, hard-coded without reading from a file.) Try to explain the problem clearly; for example, if by "datetime columns" you mean that you are using Pandas and comparing values between columns of a `DataFrame`, then **explicitly say that**, and tag the question appropriately. Show textual program output [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551).

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is the output to the csv file."?

Comment: The problem appears when I try to output my df to a csv. The „.“ will not be printed in the csv. I don’t  know the reason yet but I try to figure that out. 

Df[x][1]= 234.56 csv = 23456

Answer (score 1):

It should give the right answer:

```
t = pd.to_timedelta('0 days 00:39:16.497000')
print(t.total_seconds())

# Output
2356.497
```

Same for a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'start': [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-11 16:20:43.503000')],
        'end': [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-11 17:00:00')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print((df['end'] - df['start']).dt.total_seconds())

# Output
0    2356.497
dtype: float64
```